# cadena JSON partir

Tags: json

Apreciados Compañeros:

Estoy trabajando con una cadena json con el siguiente formato:

```
[{"id":"1","nombrelonlat":"A;28.00;-15.00"},
 {"id":"","nombrelonlat":";28.20;-15.50"},
 {"id":"2", "nombrelonlat":"b;28.01;-15.01"#"id":"3", "nombre":"c;28.05;-15.05"}]
```

a partir de la longitud latitud lo escribo en mapa gmap, todo ok excepto que no se como partir recursivamente.

Tengo el siguinte codigo

```js
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: 'http://www.grancanariamodacalida.es/json_tiendas.php',
                        async: false,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            //alert(data);
                            $.each(data, function (key, registro) {

                                var id = "";
                                var nombre = "";
                                var lon ="";
                                var lat ="";
                              });
                           $.each(registro, function (campo, valor) {

                                    //alert(campo + ": " + valor);
                                    if (campo == "id") {
                                        id = valor;
                                    }
                                   if (campo == "nombre") {
                                        var punfisdata = valor;
                                        //alert (punfisdata);
                                        if (punfisdata = ""){
                                            nombre= valor.split(";")[0];
                                            //alert(cont1.valueOf());
                                            lon = valor.split(";")[1];
                                            //alert(cont2);
                                            lat = valor.split(";")[2];
                                            //alert(cont3);
                                        }
                             });
```

Pero no me tira. Como se puede observar algunos datos vienen vacios, otros vienen con un registro, otros con dos o mas separados por #.

Alguna idea de como separarlos correctamente?

S@|u2.

Comment: No entiendo. que queres partir?? la etiqueta nombrelonlat por los valores latitud y longitud??

Comment: tengo k partir cada uno de los datos recibidos, es decir: dato1=a, log=x, lat=y  dato2=,log=,lat= dato3=b,lon=x1,lat=y1 etc

Answer (score 0):

Si te entiendo bien lo que necesitas reemplaza el código del `success` por este:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var data = [{"id":"1","nombrelonlat":"A;28.00;-15.00"}, {"id":"","nombrelonlat":";28.20;-15.50"},{"id":"2","nombrelonlat":"b;28.01;-15.01"},{"id":"3","nombre":"c;28.05;-15.05"}];                             
 
$.each(data, function(index, item){ 
     var id = item.id;
     var arreglo = item.nombrelonlat.split(";");
     var nombre = arreglo[0];
     var lon = arreglo[1];
     var lat = arreglo[2];
  
     alert("dato" + id + "=" + nombre + ", lon=" + lon + ", lat=" + lat);
   });
   

</script>
```

Ahora bien si la cadena del JSON que pones de ejemplo, es la que estas utilizando realmente. Fijate que esta mal armada, antes del id=3 hay un signo `#` que no deberia estar ahi, este se debe reemplazar por `},{` para que sea un arreglo valido para JSON.